# How to achieve wizard control arrows

Tags: photoshop, ui-design

I am new to UI development. I have a requirement to show arrows for step by step process in one of the application like shown in below figure.

[image: wizard arrows]

Can any one suggest me this kind of arrows can be shown on the page. If it is done with images how these images can be designed.

Thanks,

Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Wizard navigation control.

If you are doing in c# web programming use the following code and make the following in the aspx or HTML page and customize the content according to your needs as motioned in following [Link Click here](http://techbrij.com/stylish-asp-net-wizard-control-horizontal-sidebar-on-top)

[image]

Comment: As this is done using CSS. The arrows are not getting displayed correctly in ie 8. So I wanted to choose images option.

Comment: To fix this simply add this line in the CSS @praveen:
border-left: 30px solid brown;
right above
border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);

Comment: If i need some gradient effects like shown in the example can that be achieved using this css?

Comment: This gradient generator is great for CSS gradients: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/